# Regex for series of four digits each up to 100

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to validate a string and accepts only a series of four comma-separated digits, each up to `100`. Something like this would be valid:

```
20,30,40,50
```

and these invalid:

```
120,0,20,0
20,30,40,ss
invalid_string
```

Any thoughts?

They're used for CMYK colours. We just need to store them here, not use them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Number Range and Subroutine**

In Ruby 2+, for a compact regex, use this:

```
^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)(?:,\g<1>){3}$
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The parentheses around `([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)` match a number from 0 to 100 and define subroutine #1
- `(?:,\g<1>)` matches one comma and the expression defined by subroutine # 1
- The `{3}` quantifier repeats that three times
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: Whoa. Seriously impressed with that explanation.

Comment: Wow, so simple yet I wouldn't have guessed it. +1

Comment: Subroutines are a terrific feature that is not supported by many engines. But Ruby 2+ has it. :)

Comment: You can also name them. Like `(?<thing> [a-z]+){0} \g<thing>`

Comment: @nicooga Thanks for the up. Yes, that's right, you can name them. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd save myself the headache of using regex for a number related problem. Also the validation message will look akward so it's better to make your own:

```
validate :that_string_has_only_4_numbers_upto_100

def that_string_has_only_4_numbers_upto_100
  errors.add(:str, 'is not valid.') unless str.split(/,/).all? { |n| 1..100 === n.to_i }
end
```

Unless you a re regex jedi guru like @zx81 :p.

Comment: Marking the other one as accepted since it's in regex, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:\d{1,2},){3}\d{1,2}$
```

Try this

Comment: It is recommended to add at least some commentary to your code.